# HTML table with fixed header

Tags: html, css, header, fixed

I have created an HTMl page with three section, header, footer and a table section which is placed in between the header and footer.The header and footer is fixed at top and bottom using the css (top:0px; and bottom:0px;) with specific height.

All the three are defined in divs.The scrollable table have to be fixed in between the header and footer, ie when we zoomin and zoomout the table have to stretch in between the header and footer.

can anyone help?

Comment: Web design questions are better off being asked at doctype: http://doctype.com/

Comment: @Smashery I read somewhere they should only be lead there if their job title has *designer* in it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a div which is positioned where you want it. It sounds like the div needs to be positioned absolutely. (You would need bottom: 31px if the footer is 30px high for example.) You probably want to put the border on this div. Set the div to overflow so that the scroll bar is on the div, not the table.

Then put the table inside the div and give it width: 100%.

Setting height on a table can cause the rows to get really tall if there isn't much content. That's one reason to use the div outside the table.